# How to align my image half way outside of div container?

Tags: html, image, containers, alignment, divide

is it possible to have my image positioned half-way out of div edge? (similar to the right-side in example code). And needs to be done, with only html align function?

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;
    
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div align="left" style="height:50px;width:70px;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley2.png" width="32"></div><p></p>
<div style="height:50px;width:70px;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button6.png" width="90"></div>

<p>button outside to right abit<p>need to create similar effect on leftside</p>of simley icon above!
```

[image]How can I possibly get this to work??
any suggestions or ideas would be very helpful to me. Thx yummi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step: 1**

Just add margin-left to your image

```css
body {
    background-color: #6B6B6B;
    margin: 50px;
    
    font-family: Arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div align="left" style="height:50px;width:70px;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley2.png" style="    margin-left: -38px;" width="38"></div><p></p>
<div style="height:50px;width:70px;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);"><img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/button6.png" width="90"></div>

<p>button outside to right abit<p>need to create similar effect on leftside</p>
```

**Step: 2**

You can put that div and image into a mother div, and in that mother div you can add display flex

```css
body {
        background-color: #6B6B6B;
        margin: 50px;
        
        font-family: Arial;
        color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
```

```html
<div style="display: flex">
      <img src="http://wizzfree.com/pix/smiley2.png" style="    margin-left: -38px;" width="38">
      <div align="left" style="height:50px;width:70px;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);"></div>
</div>
```